# Ошибка установки драйвера для TP-Link Archer t2u ac-600 на Linux

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, tp-link

Вот столкнулся с такой бедой... Я сам работаю на Kali Linux, решил купить хороший WiFi адаптер для приёма сигнала и всякой роботы. Купил usb адаптер TP-Link Archer T2U AC600. С их сайта скачал драйвер под этот адаптер и установил последнюю версию gcc. Следовал инструкции, мучался перемучался, но ничего так и не получилось. Видел, что не только у меня эта проблема.

У кого был такой опыт и кто может подсказать решение установки драйвера.

@Dnis E: вывод той ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И вывод lsusb:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плюс он у меня даже не заводится (не загорается зелёная лампочка) при подключении к компьютеру. Из пакетов всё установлено (gcc, git, git build essentials.

Comment: Похожий вопрос - https://askubuntu.com/questions/499091/trying-to-install-tp-link-archer-t2u-on-ubuntu

Comment: Ваш вариант не компилируется

Comment: Firmware-ralink из реп и у меня тплинки заводились, правда не ацшные

Comment: Но только на свежем ядре. С бакпортов

Comment: @Boom что значит не компилируется? Покажите что говорит консоль

Comment: @DenisE я изменил вопрос добавив фото ошибки компиляции и вывод lsusb

Comment: Попробуйте вот этот драйвер - http://static.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/Archer_T2U_V1_150901.zip  Взято отсюда - https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-make-my-TP-LINK-Archer-T2U-work-on-Kali-Linux

Comment: Подключается в kali linux 2020.1 без проблем